# Saving tab information after swipe

Tags: android, tabs

I have 3 tabs in my application.
In my first tab I need to read JSON data from URL and using the user location. It takes about 2-3 seconds to load the page. 
My problem starts when I implemented tabs, and now every time im swiping next and back, the info is re-fetched.

I tried the following solution:
I moved my method to the **MainActivity**, and created a variable named "***isUpdated***" and updated it to **1** if the info has been fetched successfully. since then, the tab data is gone after swiping and it shows **blank empty tab.**
I understand that the tab data is wiped after swiping to another tab, but I need to save the tab content.

How I can save the tab information and show it after the user swiped to the next tabs, without re-fetching the data over and over again?

Comment: A little bit of details/code could help a lot. Are you using a ViewPager? If that is the case, you can use [setOffscreenPageLimit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)) and set the limit to 3, so fragment #1 doesn't get destroyed when you go to fragment #3 and vice versa

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you are using `ViewPager` then set your off screen page limit to something different

for example

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

should be enough for 3 tabs

Comment: Works great! Thanks! but why it's (2) and not (3)?

Comment: setOffscreenPageLimit(2) because 1 you already have on screen for example if you would have 5 tabs and your current tab index would be 0 then in memory you would have 0,1, and 2 tab but when your current tab index would be 2 then all 5 tabs would be in memory.

Comment: If I have 4 tabs, then what should I do?

Comment: @ZenBhatt just increase setOffscreenPageLimit

Comment: Thanks a lot @mstrengis .That worked like a charm. But I want to get called onPause to save fragment's data to the database when user swipes to the immediate next or previous page. In this case, onPause is not getting called. Please help me with this!

Comment: You can set setOffscreenPageLimit to default value and manage your saving in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState), but then you will have to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter, restore your views in onActivityCreated method

Comment: still onSaveInstanceState not being called when we swipe to the immediate next or previous page while setting the default value of setOffscreenPageLimit and changing FragmentPageAdapter to FragmentStatePageAdapter!

Comment: yes by default Adapter keeps previous and next item in memory if you want to save something when page is changed use ViewPager.addOnPageChangedListener