# Swipable view content disappear after swiping

Tags: listview, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager, android-tabs

My listview contents in tabs(swipable tans using view pager) seems to disappear after I swipe through tabs. i have three tabs Polygon, Line, Point. Once I swipe through all three tabs contents in listview disappear. I get my contents to populate listview by passing data from activity to each fragment. `

```
 class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    int noOfTabs;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int noOfTabs ) {
        super(fm);
        this.noOfTabs = noOfTabs;

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                SavedPolygonFragment polyFrag = new SavedPolygonFragment();

                for (int i = 0; i<savedShapes.size(); i++) {
                    bundle.putParcelable("extras" + i, savedShapes.get(i));
                }
                polyFrag.setArguments(bundle);
                return polyFrag;

            case 1:
                SavedLineFragment lineFrag = new SavedLineFragment();
                for (int i = 0; i<savedLines.size(); i++) {
                    bundle.putParcelable("extras" + i, savedLines.get(i));
                }
                lineFrag.setArguments(bundle);
                return lineFrag;
            case 2:
                SavedPointFragment pointFrag = new SavedPointFragment();
                for (int i = 0; i<savedPois.size(); i++) {
                    bundle.putParcelable("extras" + i, savedPois.get(i));
                }
                pointFrag.setArguments(bundle);
                return pointFrag;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return noOfTabs;
    }

}`
```

this is the activity from which I get the data from database for all three tabs.

My ***SavedPolygonFragment.java*** looks like this

```
package com.miraglo.drawing.fragment;


public class SavedPolygonFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
private static String LOG_TAG = SavedPolygonFragment.class.getName();

private String message = "No message";
private ListView shapeList;
private SavedShapeAdapter savedShapeAdapter;
private long        projId;
private float       scaleFactor;
private List<Shape> savedShapes = new ArrayList<>();

public SavedPolygonFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);


    for (String key : getArguments().keySet()) {
        savedShapes.add(getArguments().<Shape>getParcelable(key));
    }

    shapeList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.shapeList);


    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Here poly create",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Here",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (savedShapeAdapter != null) {
        savedShapeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {

        savedShapeAdapter = new SavedShapeAdapter(savedShapes, getActivity());
        shapeList.setAdapter(savedShapeAdapter);

        shapeList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " " + String.valueOf(((Shape) view.getTag()).getShapeId()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

OMG finally I found the fix. Posting the answer so that someday someone would not stumble around this trouble maker.. Just add this along

`mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);`

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32212032/saving-tab-information-after-swipe). Took a while to find it.